# Sending a text to a text field of a new window using Javascript

Tags: javascript, automation

I have a requirement to automate certain scenario. For that I want to open up a new window and perform some operations there.

For example: I want to open a website in a separate window and login via that window. Appreciate help to get this done using java script?

I tried as given below, but it doesn't seems working.

```
function newwin(){
var w = window.open("xxxxxxxx/login", "MsgWindow");
w.focus();
w.opener.document.getElementById('identifier').value="ab@test.com";
w.opener.document.getElementById('secret').value="abc@123";
w.opener.document.querySelector("p.css-1vtb8v1.eu2rrzg1").click();
}

newwin();
```

gives the following error.

```
371:25 TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
    at newwin (<anonymous>:366:53)
    at <anonymous>:371:1
    at <anonymous>:372:59
    at callFunction (<anonymous>:352:33)
    at <anonymous>:362:23
    at <anonymous>:363:3
```

Comment: It seems that one of your getElementById calls is returning null: no element found

Comment: You should use selenium to automate web interactions

Answer (score 0):

> For that I want to open up a new window and perform some operations there.

You're using `w.opener.document` to get your elements. That's the **current** document, not the document in the new window.

Separately, you have to give the window time to load. You can't refer to the elements within the window before they're created.

So:

```
function newwin(){
    var w = window.open("xxxxxxxx/login", "MsgWindow");
    w.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { // *** Wait for it to load
        w.document.getElementById('identifier').value="ab@test.com";
// ***  ^^^^^^^^^^----- use the new document, not `w.opener.document` (which is the same as `document`)
        w.document.getElementById('secret').value="abc@123";
        w.document.querySelector("p.css-1vtb8v1.eu2rrzg1").click();
    });
    w.focus();
}
```